Python FastAPI Delete 405 Method Not Allowed Error
When I try to delete branch with API in SwaggerUI everything works fine but when I do it in browser I receive 405 Method Not Allowed
http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_branch/3
For unknown reason Delete changes to Get and I have no idea how to avoid that.
Of course both branches 2 and 3 exists
Logs
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64422 - "DELETE /delete_branch/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64429 - "GET /delete_branch/3 HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed

My Code:
@app.delete("/delete_branch/{branch_id}")
def delete_branch(branch_id: int):
    if branch_id not in branches:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Branch not found")
    
    del branches[branch_id]


In web browser, you're sending a GET request, as you see in the Logs, but via the SwaggerUI, you send the DELETE request. That's why you see 405 error.

When you navigate to a URL in a browser you are making a GET request. If you want to make a DELETE request you will have to use xhr or fetch in JavaScript.

Solution which works with Python without browser usage
Created new run.py file with such code
import requests

response = requests.delete(f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_branch/2")


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
